# Revalidating data using mutate in SWR - Which should I use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, swr

In my app every time the user creates a new album the post request response responds with a list of the updated list of albums.

To provide a better user experience, I wanted the user to see the new content in the app without having to refresh the page.

I'm aware of the existence of SWR's mutate, but so far, I couldn't make it work.

I tried to set a 1000ms `refreshInterval` in my hook, but I wanted to know how to do it by using the mutate. Here's what I tried:

SWR hook

```
const fetcher = async (url: string, param: string) => {
    const res = await fetch(url + param);
    
   return res.json();
};


const { data, error } = useSWR(
 ["/api/albums/list?id=", appUser.id],
  (url, params) => fetcher(url, params)
);
```

Inside the `createAlbum` function:

```
const data = await response.json();

mutate("/api/albums/list", data.newAlbums, false);
```

I would be happy to get some feedback.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, the issue lies in the fact that `SWR` [internally hashes the keys used for queries/mutation](https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/651c368833164945a8ee5708eb3dd6091241f05b/src/cache.ts#L45). Therefore, the key used by the `mutate` function is simply not registered in the cache.

#### Using global mutate

To solve this problem using the `mutate` function exported directly by `swr`, it will suffice just to pass the same key to both `useSWR` and `mutate`.

```js
mutate(["/api/albums/list?id=", appUser.id]);
```

This will invalidate the cache for the hashed key. The data retrieved from your original hook will go stale, and will therefore be fetched again.

#### Using bound mutate

Another option is to take advantage of the `mutate` function bound to swr's key.

```
const { data, error, mutate } = useSWR(
   ["/api/albums/list?id=", appUser.id],
   (url, params) => fetcher(url, params)
);

/*
 * Now you can just call `mutate()` without specifying `key` argument
 */
```

docs: https://github.com/vercel/swr#bound-mutate

#### Specifying a refresh interval

For completeness, as you said, one other option would be just to set the value of `refreshInterval` prop. Forcing a refetch when desired:

```js
const { data, error } = useSWR(
   ["/api/albums/list?id=", appUser.id],
   (url, params) => fetcher(url, params),
   {
     refreshInterval: 1000, 
   }
);
```

Comment: Perfect answer, sufficed all my needs :) . One more thing, you can see that my fetcher has (url, params) as arguments. I wanted to pass an argument like so (...args), but I get a typescript error. You don't need to answer that, I already upvoted and accepted, but I wanted to know that, because I already made a question on that, but I wasn't able to get a response

Answer (score 1):

you can do as follow

```
const { data, mutate, error } = useSWR(
 ["/api/albums/list?id=", appUser.id],
  (url, params) => fetcher(url, params)
);
```

to reload swr cache just call `mutate();` .

This mutate refer to your album fetch call. Swr automatically refetch your data.

Comment: `revalidate()` is the canonical call to refresh data.

Comment: i don't see any `revalidate()` function in `swr` https://github.com/vercel/swr#manually-revalidate.

Comment: It's apparently undocumented, but it's there alright. https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/651c368833164945a8ee5708eb3dd6091241f05b/src/types.ts#L80

Answer (score 1):

The reason your UI is not refreshing after the mutate is because the first argument passed into the `mutate()` and `useSWR()` don't match each other.

The first argument is essentially a unique key that SWR uses to associate the hook with the mutate. Update your mutate call to use the same key as the hook, and it should fix your problem.

```
mutate("/api/albums/list?id=", data.newAlbums, false);
```