# Is using SWR to refresh prefetched data with SSR a good practice in a nextJS app?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, swr

Let's assume the following page:

```js
export default ({ SSRtasks }) => {
  const [ tasks, setTasks ] = useState(SSRtasks)
  const { data: freshTasks, mutate } = useSwr('/api/tasks')
  useEffect(() => freshTasks && setTasks(freshTasks), [ freshTasks ])

  return (
   <ul>{tasks.map(task => <li>{task}</li>)}</ul>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
  const SSRtasks = Task.find({ owner: id })
  return { props: { SSRtasks } }
}
```

Knowing that tasks are constantly updating,
is that correct, regarding performances? 
I can't find any documentation on this. (or at least, understand)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this part of [documentation](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs#pre-rendering) you can fetch data server side and then you can pass the server side data to swr to set the initial state

```
const { data, revalidate } = useSWR('/api/posts', fetcher, { initialData: props.posts })
```

When you fetch new data you can call revalite and swr will handle new data.
Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64249000/10801086) for more details

Comment: Okay thanks, it’s exactly what I was looking for !