# How am I expected to use SWRConfig with SSR in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, swr

I've been looking at the [documentation](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/global-configuration) and how to use it with [Next.js SSR](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs), however I'm still clueless on how to actually implement it because every way I can think of doesn't make any sense.

According to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935564/is-using-swr-to-refresh-prefetched-data-with-ssr-a-good-practice-in-a-nextjs-app) setting initial data was as simple as passing `initialData` in the options. However in the current version that doesn't exist and has been replaced with `SWRConfig`, instead of passing the data you wrap everything in a `SWRConfig` and pass in `fallbackData` (which itself the name is dumb it's used as initial data, it's only fallback data initially).

---

However if `SWRConfig` was a server component things would be fine, I can have my `layout.tsx` be

```
import {SWRConfig} from "swr";
import {fetch_data} from "@/api/data";

export default async function Layout({
  children,
}:{
  children: React.ReactNode,
}) {
  const fallbackData = await fetch_data();
  return (
    <SWRConfig value={{fallbackData}}>
      {children}
    </SWRConfig>

  )
}
```

Then inside `{children}` there could be the node

```
import useSWR from "swr";

const get_data = async () => {...}

export default function Page() {
  const {data, mutate} useSWR('/api/data', get_data);

  //Use `data` that is initially set from SWRConfig
}
```

---

However, `SWRConfig` is a client component which means that it needs to receive the data from a server component to then set it as the `fallbackData`. Resulting in a `public_layout.tsx` component but client only that receives the data from the layout to set to the `SWRConfig`

---

```
'use client';
import { SWRConfig } from "swr";
import { type DataType } from "@/util/db";

export default function Layout({
  children,
  fallbackData,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode,
  fallbackData: DataType[],
}) {
  return (
    <SWRConfig value={{fallbackData}}>
      {children}
    </SWRConfig>
  )
}
```

Then the `layout.tsx` just uses the `PublicLayout` component and passes the data

```
import {fetch_data} from "@/api/data";
import PublicLayout from './public_layout'

export default async function Layout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <PublicLayout fallbackData={await fetch_data()}>
      {children}
    </PublicLayout>
  )
}
```

Then finally it can be used, same code as `Page()` above.

---

This can't actually be the correct way to do things right?

- **If it is the correct way**, is there a cleaner and less confusing to set it up?
- **If it is the wrong way**, what am I meant to be doing?

*Also how do I pronounce "SWR"? I've been pronouncing it "sewer"*

Comment: I don't know about the question, but I also pronounce it "sewer"

Comment: Try this one: https://softans.com/question/how-am-i-expected-to-use-swrconfig-with-ssr-in-next-js/#comment-495

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not going with SWR because it was a pain to connect it with RxJS so I just did it manually and I've still got the optimistic UI that I wanted.

```js
const add_item = async (current:DataType[], new_item:DataType) => {
  //Add item and get result which is the data
  //Return data if it got it
  //Return current if it fails
} 

export default function Page({
  default_data
}: {
  default_data:DataType[] 
}) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(default_data);

  return ( //Really basic example, this would want to not have hard coded values
    <button onClick={
      const new_item = { key:"just a test bro", text:"I wanted to be the key" };
      const optimistic = [...data, new_item];
      setData(optimistic);
      setData(await add_item(data, new_item));
    }>Testing</button>
  )
  
}
```

It's laid out in a much nicer way and with this I can add in RxJS support and debounce requests and make changes in batches